# Why does the vector field $(x,y) = x \mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j}$ have an exact differential but the vector field $(-y,x)$ does not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

There are other ways of asking this question such as why does a vector field that has non zero curl not have an exact differential. In this example  if I have a gradient field like $(x,y)$ and the exact differential I assume can be easily found by integration why is it that the field $(-y,x)$ that produces a nice graph of a swirling vector field with non zero curl not have an exact differential?  What is it geometrically that prohibits this?

Comment: Because an exact differential has the form $df$ for some $f$. The curl at the level of differentials is just the exterior derivative, $d(adx+bdy) =  da \wedge dx + db \wedge dy$. But, when we take $d(df)$ we get zero since partial derivatives commute. That's the source of it calculationally, mixed partials commute. When a vector field is the gradient of a function this intrinsically links the x and y components. It's not just a slope. That linking forces the curl to be zero. This continues to be true in higher dimensions.

Comment: Interesting. I would like to know more.  I have never seen the adjective "exterior" applied to a derivative. Can you apply your explanation to the Vector field I listed above? <-y,x>  vs.  < ....>   I can let you pick the gradient field to compare against <-y,x> applying your logic.  You may have something in mind that will facilitate an easy illustration.

Comment: you can look at Chapter 10 of my notes http://www.supermath.info/AdvancedCalculus13.pdf, but there are probably better places to start reading about differential forms. As to your request, I think the answer just posted probably does what you need. The exterior derivative is just another notation for the same math in 3D.

Comment: I downloaded  supermath.info.   When I scroll on right it jumps several pages at a time making it unreadable.  It is a pdf file of several hundred pages.  How to you page through it?  Any suggestion?  I am sure there is good information in the document.

Comment: With adobe or some other pdf readers, the table of contents will link to later parts if you click on the section in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$A vector field $F = (F_{1}, F_{2})$ defined in some subset of the plane is *gradient* if and only if there exists a partially-differentiable function $f$ such that
$$
\frac{\dd f}{\dd x} = F_{1},\qquad
\frac{\dd f}{\dd y} = F_{2}.
$$
If each of these functions is itself continuously-differentiable, then $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, which implies [the mixed partial derivatives are equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives), i.e.,
$$
\frac{\dd F_{1}}{\dd y}
  = \frac{\dd^{2} f}{\dd y\, \dd x}
  = \frac{\dd^{2} f}{\dd x\, \dd y}
  = \frac{\dd F_{2}}{\dd x}.
$$

For the vector field $F(x, y) = (-y, x)$, however,
$$
\frac{\dd F_{1}}{\dd y} = -1 \neq 1 = \frac{\dd F_{2}}{\dd x}.
$$
Analytically, that's why $F$ is not gradient.

Geometrically, a gradient field cannot have closed flow lines: A short, pleasant, chain rule calculation shows that if $F = \nabla f$, and if $\Vec{x}$ is a non-constant flow line of $F$, then the function
$$
g(t) = f\bigl(\Vec{x}(t)\bigr)
$$
is strictly increasing. In particular, there do not exist $a < b$ such that $\Vec{x}(a) = \Vec{x}(b)$, i.e., the flow line $\Vec{x}$ is not closed.

That said, the [Penrose staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_stairs) is a striking visual joke answering the question, "What would the graph of a function look like if the gradient had a closed flow line?"

Comment: nice answer, I did not know the connection with the never-ending staircase.

Answer (score 2):

General theory for that provides differential forms. A form $\alpha$ is **exact** if there is a form $\beta$ such that $\alpha=d\beta$. The form $\beta$ is often called a **potential of** $\alpha$. A form $\alpha$ is **closed** if $d\alpha=0$. Because of $d^2=0$ a potential is always defined up to a closed form, i.e. $a=d\beta=d(\beta+\gamma)$ where $d\gamma=0$. This is why a potential energy of a body on Earth is defined up to constant, and why we have $+C$ in indefinite integrals.

Obviously every exact form is closed because $d^2=0$. The converse is not always true, this is why not all real functions have an indefinite integral, and why we have so rich complex analysis. But sometimes the converse is true, namely the **Poincaré lemma** says that in contractible domains every closed form is exact, that is on such domains any form with vanishing differential have a potential. For example,

1. In $\mathbb R^3$ for 1-forms: if curl is zero, then the field have a potential. Such fields called **conservative**, the work of the field along a closed path is always zero.
2. In $\mathbb R^3$ for 2-forms: if divergence is zero (**solenoidal** field: without sources and drains), then the field have potential (called "vector potential").

Note that in oriented Euclidean $\mathbb R^3$ we can identify 1- and 2-forms with vector fields, the isomorphisms provided by so-called "musical isomorphisms" (raising and lowering indices by metric) and the Hodge star. In the general case we haven't such identification.

There are many books on such subjects, I recommend "Mathematical Analysis II" by Zorich, and (just for fun) "Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics" by Arnold.